# How to disable 'touch' on new Thinkpad touchpad?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, thinkpad

I recently purchased Lenovo Thinkpad T440s which the touchpad is one big button. I am trying Ubuntu 13.10 on this machine.

How do I disable the 'touch' on the touchpad without disabling the clicking? I would like to use the trackpoint for moving the cursor and the touchpad for clicking.

Here is what I see in `xinput list`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

### Ended up doing:

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "60% 0 0% 25% 40% 60% 0% 25%"
        Option "AreaBottomEdge" "0%"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put :

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "t440 top buttons"
    MatchDriver "synaptics"
    Option "SoftButtonAreas" "60% 0 0 0 40% 60% 0 0" #Emulate right and midle buttons
    Option "Synaptics Area" "0 0 0 1" #disable moving but not buttons
EndSection
```

In /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-t440-synaptics.conf

My source for emulate right and midle buttons is here :
http://who-t.blogspot.fr/2013/12/lenovo-t440-touchpad-button.html

I still search a solution to combine middle button + trackpoint for scrolling :(

Comment: Same! Also looking for way to use the middle button for scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

Took an arch patch, applied it on a debian package, and installed it on Ubuntu (Mint). Solves your problem as well as trackpoint scrolling.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1246683/comments/40